# How to display a Div with border and 100% height inside a Div

Tags: html, css

I have a Div with `auto` height and `100%` width .Now inside this Div I have to display one more Div with remaining width available in the parent Div and `100%` height (Div Should be displayed in full page after the button of the parent Div got ended).Also i want to show the Second Div with border so that any one can know the expansion of the DIV by seeing it.
Here is the css that i am trying to add for border in Div..

```
 border: 2px solid;
 border-radius: 25px;
```

Border is coming in the Div but Div is not getting displayed in Vertical .Its getting displayed in horizontal..Here is the Fiddle Link..
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gmrq1wLh/)

Please help to resolve it ..
Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I got your request. Here's my guess:

```
.verticalDiv
{
position:relative;
height:auto;
width:  100%;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

#computationOperation
{
position:relative;
width:  100%;
    display:block;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
```

The [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmrq1wLh/1/)
Let me know it that helped!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Let me first clarify my problem ..Actaully i need to show/display the second Div with id `computationOperation` just beside the `Report` button ended till the width remaining in the webpage and height should be 100% menaing Div should be visible in full page with that amount of width remaining after the `Report` Button in the webpage

Comment: Oh! Sorry then! Hope this is the one: http://jsfiddle.net/gmrq1wLh/2/ As you can see, I put a fixed width on the computationOperation div. The only way to achieve a dynamic width length to fulfill the entire width and being indipendent from the buttons' width is by using javascript. I can mak you this little javascript script if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Done entirely understand what you are trying to do, but is this what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/5pqqeuhy/

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
}

.verticalDiv
{
position:relative;
height:100%;
width:  100%;
}

.computationOperation
{
position:relative;
height:100%;
width:  100%;
}
```

you need to set the height of html and body to 100% because by default they do not expand to the full height of your browser

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Let me first clarify my problem ..Actaully i need to show/display the second Div with id `computationOperation` just beside the `Report` button ended till the width remaining in the webpage and height should be 100% menaing Div should be visible in full page with that amount of width remaining after the `Report` Button in the webpage